# Is it possible to send multiple requests from the same port number?

Tags: dns

Let's say I run a script to simultaneously send multiple DNS requests to 3 different DNS servers, will it share the same source port number? In other words, will those servers respond to a single port? Or there will be conflict? Thanks!

Comment: No. They will use different port numbers on your computer.
Anyway, I think this question is more suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: actually @drpexe that is not 100% true.

Comment: he is talking about source ports. As you stated in your answer (if you don't specify a port) the system will choose a random one.

Answer (score 3):

First off, a "port" is just a number. All a "connection to a port" really represents is a packet which has that number specified in its "destination port" header field.

Now, there are two answers to your question, one for stateful protocols and one for stateless protocols.

For a stateless protocol (ie UDP), there is no problem because "connections" don't exist - multiple people can send packets to the same port, and their packets will arrive in whatever sequence. Nobody is ever in the "connected" state.

For a stateful protocol (like TCP), a connection is identified by a 4-tuple consisting of source and destination ports and source and destination IP addresses. So, if two different machines connect to the same port on a third machine, there are two distinct connections because the source IPs differ. If the same machine (or two behind NAT or otherwise sharing the same IP address) connects twice to a single remote end, the connections are differentiated by source port (which is generally a random high-numbered port).

Simply, if I connect to the same web server twice from my client, the two connections will have different source ports from my perspective and destination ports from the web server's. So there is no ambiguity, even though both connections have the same source and destination IP addresses.

Ports are a way to multiplex IP addresses so that different applications can listen on the same IP address/protocol pair. Unless an application defines its own higher-level protocol, there is no way to multiplex a port. If two connections using the same protocol have identical source and destination IPs and identical source and destination ports, they must be the same connection.

Comment: Nice. So does it mean that, for instance, I can simultaneously send multiple DNS requests, from a single IP address and a single port number (e.g. 65533), to 3 different DNS servers, port 53, and then all those 3 servers will respond from port 53 to port 65533? Forgive me if I got it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible, and the DNS servers should all respond.  I did this in [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/):

```
% sudo scapy
Welcome to Scapy (2.2.0)
>>> pkt1=IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP(sport=60000)/DNS(id=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="www.cnn.com"))
>>> pkt2=IP(dst="8.8.4.4")/UDP(sport=60000)/DNS(id=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="www.cnn.com"))
>>> pkt3=IP(dst="192.231.221.2")/UDP(sport=60000)/DNS(id=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="www.cnn.com"))
>>> send(pkt1); send(pkt2); send(pkt3)
.
Sent 1 packets.
.
Sent 1 packets.
.
Sent 1 packets.
>>>
```

In a tcpdump session from the same host:

```
# tcpdump -n port 60000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on xn0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
capability mode sandbox enabled
13:55:29.539612 IP 192.231.221.77.60000 > 8.8.8.8.53: 1 A? www.cnn.com. (29)
13:55:29.548176 IP 192.231.221.77.60000 > 8.8.4.4.53: 1 A? www.cnn.com. (29)
13:55:29.549064 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.231.221.77.60000: 1 5/0/0 CNAME www.cnn.com.vgtf.net., CNAME cnn-cop.gslb.vgtf.net., A 157.166.238.48, A 157.166.238.17, A 157.166.239.177 (138)
13:55:29.557538 IP 192.231.221.77.60000 > 192.231.221.2.53: 1 A? www.cnn.com. (29)
13:55:29.557821 IP 8.8.4.4.53 > 192.231.221.77.60000: 1 6/0/0 CNAME www.cnn.com.vgtf.net., CNAME cnn-56m.gslb.vgtf.net., A 157.166.248.10, A 157.166.249.10, A 157.166.248.11, A 157.166.249.11 (154)
13:55:29.558134 IP 192.231.221.2.53 > 192.231.221.77.60000: 1 0/13/0 (240)
```

Three packets out to different servers from the same IP+port, three packets in answer.